# Bi-directional access to Github Gist from Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: chrome, cloud-storage, source-code, github

The title kind of sums it up.

I would like to be able to insert a Gist into my developer console, or save a function I've been working on as a Gist.

I know about Chrome's snippets feature, but I have two problems with that.

1. I have to execute the snippet each time I want to use it.  This can be a pain in the butt in certain circumstances, but if this was the only problem, I could live with it.  However, I'd prefer to have a global command line function(s) available that I could say something like (`listGists();getGistByName("gistName")`), etc. - and I'd like to have the function(s) for working with Gists injected into the global scope on page load.
2. I have had several occasions where my Chrome profile has gotten corrupted.  This is a known issue on Windows that may or may not now be fixed (it's been a while since it happened), but it resulted in me losing all my snippets.  Even if this issue was fixed, I'd still prefer to have them backed up in the cloud, where I know they would never get deleted and would be available on different devices.